# IBM MobileFirst Java adapter for WS SOAP

Tags: java, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I have a MobileFirst example, of an HTML5 page that calls a single REST WS (Java Adapter), this Java Adapter returns a string and shows
in a div, this works is ok.

I do exactly the same, a Java adapter with the same function, but that is SOAP WS.

How I can do?

Thank you very much,

Comment: What did you write thus far? always add CODE. Also, did you read the HTTP adapter tutorial that talks about SOAP?

Comment: Also, are you using mobilefirst platform 7.0 with Java adapters or actually JavaScript HTTP adapter?

Answer (score 1):

Since you mention Java adapters, I will assume then that you are in fact using MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.0.

You can view the following video in order to learn how to use SOAP in your Java adapter: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/2015/03/24/getting-familiar-ibm-mobilefirst-platform-foundation-java-adapters/ around minute 21.

There is no written material on this, so review the video.